# SIGTERM does not terminate script

Tags: sh

I am trying to understand this script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

trap "pkill -f sleep" term

sleep 1000
```

After running the script, I would like to stop it by sending a `SIGTERM`:

```sh
# run script in the background
$ ./signals.sh &
[1] 5389

# check if script is running
$ ps aux | grep 'signals.sh\|sleep' | grep -v grep
sergioro  5389  0.0  0.0 216520  3112 pts/0    S    09:07   0:00 sh ./signals.sh
sergioro  5390  0.0  0.0 214984   708 pts/0    S    09:07   0:00 sleep 1000

# send SIGTERM to script
$ pkill -fe signals.sh
sh killed (pid 5389)

# why hasn't the script stopped after receiving SIGTERM?
$ ps aux | grep 'signals.sh\|sleep' | grep -v grep
sergioro  5389  0.0  0.0 216520  3112 pts/0    S    09:07   0:00 sh ./signals.sh
sergioro  5390  0.0  0.0 214984   708 pts/0    S    09:07   0:00 sleep 1000

# send SIGTERM to `sleep` command
$ pkill -fe sleep
sleep killed (pid 5390)
Terminated

# script has stopped
$ ps aux | grep 'signals.sh\|sleep' | grep -v grep
```

My question is how to stop the script by sending `SIGTERM` to the script itself and not to the `sleep` command? And why is the `trap` in the script not terminating the sleep command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shell can process `trap` only after `sleep` finishes.

This can achieve what you expected :

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

trap "pkill -f sleep" term

sleep 1000 & wait
```

See the SIGNALS section of the man page, especially the last paragraph:

> If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal  for
>          which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes.  When bash is waiting for an asynchronous  command  via
>          the  wait  builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been
>          set will cause the wait builtin to return immediately with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.